# Swagger effect on REST API performance

Tags: java, performance, rest, swagger-ui

I am planning to implement Swagger for our REST API's. But the main worry we have is, did swagger slows down the service. 
?1 .Since the swagger annotations will be placed on the REST calls, so will they will be called every time we hit a REST service or will it be called only when there is change in service signature??
?. Will this extra overhead on the service signature will effect the response time (performance) of the service. ??

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for you would be using maven with your project; to avoid "slowing down" your API.

If you are using JAX-RS or Spring you could use this [library](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin). Unlike swagger-core, swagger-maven-plugin does not actively serve the spec with the rest of the application; it generates the spec as a build artifact to be used in downstream Swagger tooling.

Comment: I don't think i got completely what you are trying to say as in what different way of implementation, would it be possible to provide any demo example.